# how to set multiple parameter in preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex

With the use of `preg_replace()` I want to change string of 
`http://www.vaidehielink.com/` to  `www.vaidehielink.com`.

I have succeeded to get result of `www.vaidehielink.com/` with the following code:

```
$str = "http://www.vaidehielink.com/";
$pattern= '(http://)';
$copy_date = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

But I am looking for a pattern to remove the trailing `/`

Comment: is it not possible with preg_replace()

Comment: Regular expressions aren't necessary for this. If you really want to find the host part of a URL, you can use PHP's built-in `url_parse` function instead of your own code. (Of course, if you're just practicing your regular expressions, then go ahead...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides, that you are missing delimiters, just change your pattern and your replacement to this:

```
$pattern= "/^(http:\/\/)(.*?)(\/)?$/";
echo $copy_date = preg_replace($pattern, "$2", $str);
```

output:

```
www.vaidehielink.com
```

Basically your only grab the string between `http://` and `/` if there is one.

Comment: can you explain the $pattern= "/^(http:\/\/)(.*?)(\/)?$/";

Comment: @abhiAhere `^(http:\/\/)` matches `http://` at the beginning of the string and `(\/)?$` matches `/` 0 or 1 time at the end of the string; And you just grab the middle part of this, which is `(.*?)`

Comment: @ Rizier123  thanks i was googling for explanation of pattern, but not getting appropriate answer .this answer help me a lot,

Comment: @abhiAhere Then I can only recommend you a very useful site: https://regex101.com/ <- Just throw/ or test your regex'es in there and to the right you get a really good and detailed explanation

Comment: @ Rizier123 thanks again.I will go through the link you suggested

Comment: one question arises what is $2

Comment: @abhiAhere Ah, yeah, that's basically just the second group (`()`, here `(.*?)`). So you replace the matched pattern with the second group. And that is `$2`

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex.

```
$copy_date = str_replace(array('http:', '/'), '', $str);
```

Or probably the proper tool:

```
$copy_date = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: I first fell for the same. He only wants to delete the slash, when it is at the end.

Comment: OK, where did you see that?

Comment: *so that trailing slash can also be removed.* <- here

Comment: Yes, in a host name there can't be a `/`. So it would be part of the path.

Comment: You're right, but since OP wrote: *i want to change string* I didn't made the assumption, that it has to be a valid url. But I think now/that would be up to OP, to clarify if his string is a valid url.